# What's the table name for a defined name in the scope of a worksheet?

Tags: sql, excel, delphi, odbc

I'm trying to query a defined name in a worksheet scope with SQL using ODBC.

I already know that this works:

```
SELECT * FROM [worksheet1$]       -- Query a whole worksheet
SELECT * FROM [worksheet1$A1:C10] -- Query A1:C10 of a worksheet
SELECT * FROM myname              -- Query a workbook scoped defined name
```

Note that `myname` is workbook scoped and not worksheet scoped.

I would have expected that something like in Excel formulas works for the ODBC table name as well:

```
SELECT * FROM worksheet1!myname   -- Query a worksheet scoped defined name
```

However this doesn't work, I tried some syntax variations of this.

Is this possible and if it is, what's the syntax to use?

*Note for Delphi developers: The `A1:C10` syntax causes trouble in `TADOQuery`, you have to set `ParamCheck` to `False` in order for this to work.*

**Update:**

I'm using the `Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)` Version `12.00.6606.1000` that comes with `Microsoft Office 2007`.

I have checked that the Delphi database components I'm using are behaving the same way as Microsoft Query and Microsoft Access 2007.

Comment: One presumes that `[worksheet1$myname]` does not work?

Comment: Have you tried this from Delphi only, or also from one of the other MS Office products? For example MS Access?

Comment: @eggyal This works, but only in version 14 (and newer) of the ODBC driver as I found out by trial & error.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an Excel file (xlsx in my case) that has the following names (Excel formula notation):

- `myname`
- `worksheet1!myname`
- `worksheet2!myname`

Different versions of the Excel ODBC driver have different behavior:

The `Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)` Version `12` that comes with `Microsoft Office 2007` behaves like this:

The namespaces are flattened.

All you can query is `SELECT * FROM myname`. Apparently this returns the data from the first name that is defined.

The `Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)` Version `14` that comes with `Microsoft Office 2010` ([and can be downloaded separatly from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)) behaves like this:

You can indeed query all three of them:

```
SELECT * FROM myname
SELECT * FROM [worksheet1$myname]
SELECT * FROM [worksheet2$myname]
```

So this was apparently fixed in `Microsoft Office 2010`.

The fix is not backwards compatible. When you had a worksheet scoped name defined in 2007, you could query it using the `myname` syntax which only works for workbook scoped names in 2010. So caution is needed when handling this situation across different versions of Office.

Note: If the download link ever becomes dead, search for `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to help you figure out the name Delphi is looking for.

1. Drop a combo box on a form.
2. Run the following code to populate the combobox with the names Delphi will accept: `AdoConnection1.GetTableNames(ComboBox1.Items,True);`
3. Run the app. The combobox should give you a list of queryable names.

Using Delphi XE2 and Office 2010 (excel file saved as office 97 xls format) I created a worksheet scoped named range (sheet1!numberlist) and ran an ADO query in Delphi. The query was `SELECT * FROM [sheet1$numberlist]`. Maybe it's your ODBC driver?

Comment: There are indeed different ODBC drivers, I'll check this. The GetTableNames call is a nice idea.

Comment: The driver I'm using is `Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)` Version `12.00.6606.1000`