# Combine data from two sheets to form conglomerated output (similar to database outer join)

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have an Excel workbook (.xlsx / .xlsm) with the following two sheets (simplified for example's sake):

**Sheet 1:**

```
Student_Id:    Name:    Age:    Sex:     ...
1              Bobby    10      Male     ...
2              Suzy     11      Female   ...
3              Mike     10      Male     ...
4              Sally    9       Female   ...
 ....
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
Class:    Student_Id:
Math      1
Math      2
Math      4
English   3
English   4 
 ....
```

---

Now, I would like to create an output sheet which is a mixture of the two, looking something along the lines of:

**Output:**

```
Class:    Name:    Age:    Sex:     ...
Math      Bobby    10      Male     ...
Math      Suzy     11      Female   ...
Math      Sally    9       Female   ...
English   Mike     10      Male     ...
English   Sally    9       Female   ...
 ....
```

---

Now, I know this is fairly easy to do using `VLOOKUP`s and `INDEX`, `MATCH` functions and I've already done that, but my question is whether there's a better feature existing in Excel to accomplish this.

I'm thinking of just using ADO to query the two sheets and output it, but I'm just feeling convinced there has to be a better way / built in feature.

**Extra notes:**

1. My data doesn't need to be live - meaning that it doesn't need to be formulas that will slow down Excel - which I know I can do with Copy / Paste Special, Values.
2. I know of Power Query, but I'm trying not to use something that will require my users to install an add-in (but macros within the workbook would be ok).

Comment: If you don't need formulas of Excel, why don't you use a database directly, for example MS Access?
Otherwise you can also try to [Run SQL on an Excel table (sheet)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/run-sql-on-excel-table).

Comment: I could show you how I would do it reading all the data up using a recordset, but I don't know if that is any better then using VLookups & Index, Match functions, or doing some slick query of the worksheets.

Comment: @agold, I completely agree, it's just that the users want the data in Excel and that's my given limitation.

Comment: @MatthewD, thanks so much. I know how to do it using a recordset and will probably go that way, it just strikes me as odd that Excel doesn't have this built in somewhere using the Data / ListObject kind of library.... I was just wondering if there was an Excel feature I didn't know if that could do this more intelligently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done with a built-in feature of Excel. It is called `Microsoft Query`.

It can be found on the Ribbon under `Data` - `Other Sources` - `From Microsoft Query`.

You select your workbook from the ancient looking dialog (it can be the same workbook).

It will complain that it cannot find any tables, Click OK. And then from the dialog go into Options and check the box for System Tables. You will now be able to select the columns you want from your two source tables. You can join them in the query builder like this:

[image]

Now select `Return Data to Microsoft Excel` from the File menu.

An Import Data dialog will display allowing you to select where you want the new table of data to appear.

You can even set properties to refresh periodically, if you want.

Note: this solution requires no VBA and no worksheet formulas. It produces a joined table based on the SQL you create in Microsoft Query (which is a built-in component of Excel). The resulting table can be static or dynamic.

Comment: Just poetic, @Hero!!! - It took some fighting, but did EXACTLY what I wanted in the most beautiful way!!! - **Thank you SO MUCH**!!!

Comment: You are welcome. It's funny... this has been in Excel forever and most people never discover it. It is well hidden.

Comment: Agreed! - And once I moved it into VBA and started playing with the SQL text directly, DARN is it powerfully EXACTLY what I wanted! - Truly, thank you!!