# VBA SumIF between two Arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have two large tables of data that I have been playing around with to try and minimize computing resources. The two tables roughly have the following information:

1) Freight Billing information

```
InvoiceNum | TrackingNum | Weight | BilledAmt | IncentiveCredit
```

2) ERP Generated Invoice Information

```
InvoiceNum | Weight | ProductRev | FreightRev | TaxAmt | DiscountAmt
```

I'm conducting an analysis between what the freight company is charging per order (Freight Cost) compared to what we charge customers per order (Freight Revenue).  Additionally, I'm hoping to compare reported weights for both the freight company and our company to audit accuracy.

There will only be one instance of the invoice in the ERP data, but there can be multiple lines in the freight data with the same invoice number. A simple SumIF column would work well if the tables weren't both approximately 100,000 lines. I know that working with Arrays is generally much faster than working directly with ranges, so I started there.

```
Option Explicit   

Sub compareFreightData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declare Sheets
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim billingSht As Worksheet
Set systemSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SystemData")
Set billingSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UPSData")


'Declare Arrays
Dim billingArray As Variant
Dim systemArray As Variant

'Declare timer
Dim t As Long 
t = Timer

'Add additional header info
systemSht.Range("K3").Value = "BilledTotal"
systemSht.Range("L3").Value = "IncentiveCredits"
systemSht.Range("M3").Value = "OrderWeight"

'Put info into arrays
upsArray = billingSht.ListObjects("UPSCSVFiles").DataBodyRange.Value 
systemArray = systemSht.Range("A4:J" & systemSht.Cells(systemSht.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row).Value 

'ReDim to have the three additional columns in the array
ReDim Preserve systemArray(1 To UBound(systemArray, 1), 1 To UBound(systemArray, 2) + 3)

'****************************CALCULATE THE SUMIF*******************
'
'

'Timer
 Debug.Print "Timer", Timer - t
```

Some ideas I had were the following:

- If there is a way to sum all the items in a filtered array then print the amount. (I think Filter() only works with single dimension arrays)
- Loop through billing array, find the location in system array using MATCH, then add to system array (this seems very slow)

Mostly, I believe there is some easier way that I am missing and any input or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use a table with a total row, which would have a total for each column. then just sum the cells in the total row

Comment: @jsotola That doesn't do anything to compare the tables. I may need to convert them into Access Databases then use an SQL Join clause.

Comment: you can run SQL queries on excel worksheet data directly, even from within the same workbook ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/run-sql-on-excel-table