# VBA find unique values in col a where date in col B is equal to value in col C

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies, I have no code because I am not quite sure where to start. This doesn't seem like it should be that difficult, yet I am completely stuck..

I have names in col A, and dates in col B.

There are duplicates in both the names and the dates.

In col C there are a list of the unique dates.

I was trying to write some code that would tell me the unique number of names in col A where the date was x in col C.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Thanks

```
Col A      Col B         Col C          Col D
name       dates        Unique dates    
bob        02/01/2000   02/01/2000  
fred       02/01/2000   03/01/2000  
harry      03/01/2000       
bob        03/01/2000       
fred       02/01/2000       
harry      03/01/2000
```

So in col D, I want a number to be there when I run the code, the number would be the number of unique names against each unique date. So for 02/01/2000 in col D the number would be 2

Comment: Start with the user prompt that defines what the x date is. That should be straightforward and will give you momentum. Then consider whether to create a sql query ([this could be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984865/5936117)) or filter and loop.

Comment: Hang on a sec, you say col C are unique dates and you want a list of unique names associated with that unique date? There will only be one name. Seems like `Index(Match())` would do the trick.

Comment: No not the unique names, I want the number of unique names.

Comment: Shouldn't it always be 1 if col c contains unique values thoigh?

Comment: So if the names are in col A, I want to be able to run something which will look at a date, and for that date, tell me the number of unique names that have this date against them

Comment: I'll add in some data, I think it will be easier to explain this way

Comment: I still don't understand the specifics, but a sql query is probably fastest. If you can't get the connection to work the loop is probably easier. Let me know when you post some code and I can try to help.

Comment: That's the problem, every time I try to write something, I realise I have no idea where to start... my SQL is very basic but I think the code for it would look something like this                                                           Select count distinct (col A)
From table
Where col B in(unique date1, unique date2, unique date3)                             Do you know how to reproduce this in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would do as you want, but I am using Sheet2 as a helper sheet to remove duplicates before counting the occurrences, so as long as you have a Sheet2 and column D on Sheet1 has Zeros in them, then it should work:

```
Sub foo()
    LastRow2 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last Row on column A of Sheet1
    Columns("A:B").Copy 'Copy the first two columns of Sheet1.
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste 'Paste the columns into Sheet2
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    LastRow3 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Count the number of rows on Sheet2 Column A
    Sheet2.Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRow3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes ' Remove duplicates on Sheet2

    For i = 2 To LastRow3 'Loop through Sheet2 to find expected values
        For j = 2 To LastRow2 ' Loop through Sheet1 Column D to compare values
            If Sheet1.Cells(j, 3).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value Then ' If values on Sheet1 Column D match those on Sheet2 Column B Then
                Sheet1.Cells(j, 4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(j, 4).Value + 1 ' Increment Column D on Sheet1 by one (to be able to increment the first/original value should be 0)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run this code on the above table, it doesn't like the paste method (it works with pastevalues, but then it doesn't like lastrow2 & 3. Is it possible to have lastrow2 & 3 as Range("D1:D & Range("D1").currentregion.rows.count) instead?

Comment: Also, if it's not too much trouble, could you comment the code?

Comment: Yeah, I guess this could also work, but I have tested it and it works well for me...? I will comment the code too, sorry.

Comment: Just re-ran it and it worked, I must have been doing something wrong. Thank you very much!!!