# How to insert data from selected filed in Excel file to database in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

Normally, to insert data for 4 tables in database. I used 4 Excel files (1 Excel per 1 database's table) by BULK INSERT.

But, I waste so much time and my power by using 4 Excel files.

I want to use just ONE Excel file which have 4 data zones per 4 tables in database. I searched in Google but nobody or document write about it. What query do I need?

> A1-B9 for table 1
>
> C17-D20 for table 2
>
> E3-F13 for table 3
>
> I6-L14 for table 4

[image]
**THANKS!**

Comment: Could you explain more the problems you want to overcome? Is the issue with more excel files having to create/maintain them, or in the processing of them?

Comment: this is not a big issue and i think you need to specify the area that you need to separate the different sheets and then you can read according to that

Comment: You can use select.

Comment: more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table

Comment: Thank everyone. I got it within 2days !!!