# How to use formulas in Excel to pick a value from a sheet similar to SQL

Tags: excel, database, formula

I want to use a sheet in Excel as a DB and want to be able to query a list based on the following criteria:

SELECT ColumnA FROM QuestionsSheet WHERE ColumnG=1 AND ColumnD=1 AND ColumnB=1 ORDER BY ColumnF

How can I use a formula to populate a list of values from Column A?

Comment: Is anything in this thread relevant?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522

Comment: if I understand it correctly you dont want to run the sql, you just put it there to explain what the the filtering/sorting should be, right? In such case you could simply use pivot table. ColumnG, ColumnD and ColumnB into Filters, ColumnA and ColumnF into Rows and sort by ColumnF.