# show a missing value from one column compared to another

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

I'm moving a tracker from google sheets to Excel however the formula in excel does not work.

[image: Capture]

When i download the new data I want to know if any new vins have been added. In google sheets it would look at the `MASTER` then look at the `Download` and if there was any new vins it would show them in the `New VINs`. Please see the google sheets formula:

```
 =IFERROR(QUERY('download'!$A$2:$Y, "Select W where not lower(Q) contains 'core' and (B=30 or B=35) and not W matches '"&JOIN("|", ' MASTER'!$E2:$E)&"'"))
```

Basically I need the excel version of this formula

Comment: you can use Match to test if VIN found in master, if error then new.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Google spreadsheet's QUERY formula is actually based on [Google Visualization API Query Language](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) which you can only find in Google spreadsheet.

Unfortunately, there's nothing similar in excel. In addition, There is no inbuilt regex/ formulaic version of regex in excel.

#### Further Reading

[SQL query in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table)