# Pivot table from a multicolumn table with Yes/No fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Yes, I know the title is horrible but I couldn’t think of a better way to ask it.  The input table looks something like that:

```
 Item no.|Type1|Type2|Type3
 --------+-----+-----+-----
 Item 1  | Yes | No  | Yes
 Item 2  | No  | Yes | Yes 
 Item 3  | Yes | No  | Yes
```

etc., etc.  There are more items and types.  I would like to create a pivot table showing the total of `Yes` in each `Type`, so something like:

```
 Type   |Total
 -------+-----
 Type 1 | 2
 Type 2 | 1
 Type 3 | 3
```

I can easily do it with an array formula (and that's how it's working at the moment) or as a [SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table) but for the sake of end users of this report I would like to have it as a pivot table.

If it's a pivot table I don't have to explain the magic behind and people just assume it's right.  If I put any VBA/SQL etc. code behind the spreadsheet I have to explain all the inner workings and it's already treated suspiciously.  For some reason people don't have that problem with pivot tables.  Go figure.

Anyway, is it doable and how so?

Comment: Are you open to a helper column? If so, add new column with formula `COUNTIF(Row, "Yes")` and then simply add that column to the value field as `Sum` and `Item No.` Field in rows. I've seen you answer questions so I doubt you want this, but just throwing it out there just in case

Comment: What about `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform`?  It would basically be an unpivot/filter/group and count type of operation. And, perhaps, since it's part of Excel, the users would have as much confidence in that as in Pivot Tables.

Comment: @urdearboy - I would prefer to avoid this option.  I like to keep data untouched and do calculations separately but it's going to be an option if I don't find another way.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a pivot without going the extra steps. If the idea is to make it straight forward **and reproducible** for all while minimizing questions, newbies are more likely to understand `COUNTIF` in comparison to more sophisticated options as you (*and @RonRosenfeld*) have stated.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I'm considering this option as well.  I don’t think all potential users have this plug-in installed (which will create another problem) but at the moment I think it’s my preferred option.