# Sort Excel Pivot Table with multiple rows and one value colum

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I am trying to sort an Excel Pivot table by a final value.
**The pivot table gets its data from an OLAP data source (SSAS).**

I will try to explain the problem with the help of a simple example.
Suppose I have two Rows (Bicycle, Colour) and one Value (Sales).

[image]

I am just trying to sort the table by sales, to highlight the top items, like this:
[image]

However if I sort Sales highest to lowest it sorts by the best selling colour in each bicycle type, like this:

[image]

Similarly if I click in the Bicycle column and select **Sort-->More Sort Options**, it just sorts Bicycle by the highest combined sales for each bicycle type:

[image]

I have also tried creating an MDX Calculated Measure that combines the Bicycle and Colour columns but could not make it work.

I then tried pulling the data into an Excel table but that did not work either, as a table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report.

This seems that conceptually it should be quite simple. If it is not possible can someone provide the appropriate online reference. And also potential workarounds.

Comment: You will need to use a helper column or Power Pivot.  https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/pivot-table/sorting-pivot-table-by-two-columns

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have clarified in the question that this is for an OLAP data source. The solution you suggested does not apply because you cannot create formulas in a PivotTable that is connected to an Online Analytical Processing (OLAP) data source.https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/calculate-values-in-a-pivottable-11f41417-da80-435c-a5c6-b0185e59da77

Comment: Don't use a pivot, run a SQL query from the data table.

Comment: The data source is not SQL. It is an MDX query from a SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) cube.

Comment: Use SQL on the table table in Excel - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table