# How to find the first and last values in a conditional loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I'm creating a report on a stock index where I am supposed to get the annual open to close net change in stock price for each stock in the market. I have panel data with an observation for each stock every day of the year. I'm currently using a conditional for loop to create annual total volume as well. Is there any way for me to select the first and last values in a conditional to select the annual open and close of a stock? Column 1 is the name of the stock so I am using that as the conditional for when the stock changes. Here is what I have thus far. Column 4 is daily open and column 5 is daily close for the observation.

```
'Establish variables
Dim ticker As String
Dim change_price As Double
Dim change_percent As Double
Dim volume As Double
Dim annual_open As Double
Dim annual_close As Double


' Keep track of each stock the summary table
  Dim Summary_Table_Row As Integer
  Summary_Table_Row = 2


For i = 2 To 800000
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        'create a list of stocks
        ticker = ticker + Cells(i, 1).Value
        'total volume for each stock
        volume = volume + Cells(i, 7).Value
        'annual_open = ?
        'annual_close = ?

         ' Print the stock in the Summary Table
      Range("H" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = ticker

      ' Print the stock volume to the Summary Table
      Range("I" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = volume

      ' Add one to the summary table row
      Summary_Table_Row = Summary_Table_Row + 1

      'reset the stock name
      ticker = ""

      ' Reset the Brand Total
      volume = 0


    ' If the cell immediately following a row is the same stock...
    Else

      ' Add to the stock total
      volume = volume + Cells(i, 7).Value


    End If
Next i
```

Comment: [Query the data-range with sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table) to get those values by a sql-statementt (Sum(),  Count(),, Min(), Max()  grouped by stock),. Avoid using implicit references to`ActiveSheet (e.g. using Cells(), Range() without explicit defining the sheet (and workbook) ! Have a look at [RubberduckVBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/) to get hints on that.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been more clear if you add a screenshot of your data layout. And also, need some clarification - what are the first and last values? Are those are min and max?

Or those are first "open" occurrence and last "close" in appropriate columns? If so, you may try doing this way:

```
' This will be first stock's open
annual_open = Cells(2, 4).Value

For i = 2 To 800000

    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then

        '[Your code]

        ' Here, i is the last row of the current stock, so assign it
        annual_close = Cells(i, 5).Value

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Handler for your "annual_open" and "annual_close"
        ' because lines after will overwrite "annual_open" with new value

        '   [Add code here]

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        ' Here, i + 1 is the first row of next stock
        ' so assign it
        annual_open = Cells(i + 1, 4).Value

        '[Your code]

    Else
        ' If stock is the same do nothing to "annual_open" and "annual_close"
        '[Your code]



    End If
Next i
```