# SQL question: How to get a list of cities?

Tags: sql

Pretend there is a database with every city in the world and a unique ID to go with each one. I have a list of 50 IDs in one column of an excel document.

How do I return the names of the 50 cities most efficiently? Do I really need to do a WHERE clause with ID# OR ID# ....etc?

Answer (score 1):

You just do a in

```
select cityname  from tableofeverycity a where id in (select id from tbl50 ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL terms you would be looking for something like
`SELECT names FROM tablofcities`

This code assumes that you want them in the same order that they are listed in.

Because you mention that these are listed in a excel document rather than a database, it makes it a little different.

I'd recommend checking out the following link for more details on your question.

[How to run a SQL query on an Excel table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, create a formula that is essentially (assuming the empty cell is A1):

```
empty    
1         =B1&","&A2
2         =B2&","&A3
3         =B3&","&A4
```

You can write the formula once and copy it down.

The results will look like:

```
1         ,1
2         ,1,2
3         ,1,2,3
```

Go to the 50th row and copy the formula.

Next, paste them into a query in your favorite GUI:

```
select c.*
from cities c
where cityid in (<paste list here>);
```

Remove the first comma.

Run the query.