# Powershell Excel Master Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell

This is a long winded one but I will try and shorten it.

I have a master spreadsheet exported from our MIS system each school term and it gives me all the classes and who is in them for a specific school year.

The only problem is that it comes as one massive sheet within one workbook.

It looks like this:

[Redacted Master Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7KgD.png)

My end goal is to have one master workbook with each class cut and pasted into a separate sheet, and then the name of that sheet is the 'class code' which is the `{redacted}` part at the top of each section.

This has been done manually until now but it takes hours.

Is there a way in powershell to do this? I need the data from `Class List Report: ...` to `Males: X Females: X` into their own sheet within the workbook and then name the sheet the class code. Unfortunately the classes are different lengths so I cant do it based on counting the number of cells.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about [querying the workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18798522/503046) with SQL?

Comment: @vonPryz How would SQL know where the tables are though? They are all different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably do what you need given the image you provided. Essentially it opens the Workbook gets the main sheet parses it based on the key phrase. Then creates new sheets with the data between the start of each key phrase named by the identifier within the key phrase.

```
$ExcelFile="SO61954371.xlsx"
$MainSheetName="Sheet1"
$splitOnLike="Class List Report*"
$newExcelFile="SO61954371AA.xlsx"


#create Excel Object
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
#open Workbook
$WorkBook = $xl.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile)  
#grab main sheet
$mainSheet=$WorkBook.sheets.Item("$MainSheetName")

$classStart=@()
#loop through used rows
for($i=1; $i -le $mainSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;$i++){
    #get cell in row $i Column 1(A)
    $cell=$mainSheet.Cells.Item($i,1)
    #check if start of table
    if($cell.Text -like "$splitOnLike")
    {
    #make object with class code and starting cell
    $classStart+=[pscustomobject]@{
        classCode=($cell.text.split(":")[1] -split "as")[0].trim()
        Cell=$cell
        }
    }
}

#Loop though tables
for($c=0; $c -lt $classStart.Count;$c++){
    #create new sheet after last sheet
    $Nsheet=$WorkBook.Sheets.Add($($WorkBook.Worksheets|Select -Last 1))
    #name sheet
    $Nsheet.name=$classStart[$c].classCode
    #get and copy from current class to start of next
    if($c -ne ($classStart.Count-1)){
        $range=$mainSheet.Range("A$($classStart[$c].Cell.Row):$([char](64 + $($mainSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count)))$($classStart[$c+1].Cell.Row-1)")
        $range.Copy() | out-null
        $nsheetrange=$Nsheet.Range("A1")
        $Nsheet.paste($nsheetrange)
    }
    else{
    #for last class get and copy from start of class to end of usable range
        $range=$mainSheet.Range("A$($classStart[$c].Cell.Row):$([char](64 + $($mainSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count)))$($mainSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)")
        $range.Copy() | out-null
        $nsheetrange=$Nsheet.Range("A1")
        $Nsheet.paste($nsheetrange)
    }
}
#save the file
$workbook._SaveAs($newExcelFile)

#kill the Excel instance and cleanup
$xl.Quit()
Remove-Variable -Name xl
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Not a problem! Please mark the answer as useful if it worked for you, so it can be ranked towards top answer.

Comment: Quick question, to delete Sheet1 once its finished, ive added ```$workbook.worksheets.item($MainSheetName).Delete()``` just before the save line, but it doesnt seem to delete the sheet, any ideas?

Comment: This actually was harder than I thought.  The give away was that when executing you can hear a "ding"  What was happening is that the com object essentially a hidden excel window was prompting "Are you sure you want to delete this"

The fix was to disable the alert before deleting

$WorkBook.Application.DisplayAlerts =$false
$mainsheet.delete()
$WorkBook.Application.DisplayAlerts =$true