# VLookup takes too long - need alternative

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a procedure which looks for a specific value in another workbook, and returns a corresponding value (a VLookup, essentially).

I have a VLookup method in place which works but works incredibly slow (takes 12 minutes to complete) due to the large nature of the file (19 columns, 300,000+ rows) so I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing this.

Here's what I have - file names will be variable in accordance with the date which is why I've created much of the above to account for these variables e.g. the files are always in file paths with the associated month:

```
'returns Connection Classification values from Dataset wb to Reporting Tool
Sub testVLookup()

'declaring b, c, d, e as column ranges
Dim b As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim e As Range

'declaring the columns from each
Dim AccNoValue As Integer
Dim AccColumnNumber As Long
Dim AccColumnLetter As String
Dim AccDSColumnNumber As Long
Dim AccDSColumnLetter As String
Dim AccDSNumberCol As Long
Dim DPDEndMRColumnNumber As Long
Dim DPDEndColumnNumber As Long
Dim DPDEndColumnLetter As String
Dim DPDEndMRColumnLetter As String
Dim DPDEndNumberCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim VLValue As Long
Dim VLRes As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myFile As String
Dim otherFile As String
Dim DailyShout3 As Workbook
Dim MonthlyRepTool As Workbook
Dim sheet As String
Dim pStr As String

'Declaring year of 2 month Daily Shout file
Dim Year_2M As Integer
Dim Year_3M As Integer

'Declaring location of 2 month Daily Shout file
Dim Month_2M As String
Dim Month_3M As String

'Declaring location of 2 month Daily Shout file
Dim MonthChar_2 As String
Dim MonthChar_3 As String

'Declaring year value of 1 month & 2 month
'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
Year_2M = Format(Date - 57, "YYYY")
Year_3M = Format(Date - 87, "YYYY")

'Declaring month value of 1 month & 2 month
'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
Month_2M = Format(Date - 57, "MM")
Month_3M = Format(Date - 87, "MM")

'This translates the current month from number to character format
MonthChar_2 = MonthName(Month_2M, False)
MonthChar_3 = MonthName(Month_3M, False)

'opens the workbook before
'specifiying the file locations
pStr = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\Monthly Files" & "\" & Year_2M & "\" & _
Month_2M & ". " & MonthChar_2 & " " & Year_2M & "\"

myFile = "Daily Shout"
otherFile = "Monthly Reporting Tool"
sheet = "MASTERFILE_" & Year_2M & Month_2M

    'checking to see that dataset wb is open, declaring it as Dataset
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*" & myFile & "*" Then
           Set DailyShout3 = Workbooks(wb.Name)
        End If
    Next wb
    
    'checking to see that the reporting tool is open, declaring it as MonthlyRepTool
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like otherFile & "*" Then
           Set MonthlyRepTool = Workbooks(wb.Name)
        End If
    Next wb
    
    LastRow = MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
With MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(sheet).Rows(1)
    Set b = .Find("DPD End " & Left(MonthChar_3, 3), LookIn:=xlValues)
    DPDEndMRColumnNumber = b.Column
    'Convert To Column Letter
    DPDEndMRColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, DPDEndMRColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    If Not b Is Nothing Then
    DPDEndMRColumnNumber = b.Column
End If
End With

'finding the column number and letter for account number in daily shout file
With MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(sheet).Rows(1)
    Set c = .Find("Account Number", LookIn:=xlValues)
    AccColumnNumber = c.Column
    'Convert To Column Letter
    AccColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, AccColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    AccColumnNumber = c.Column
End If
End With

'finding the column letter and number for HET Lead in the Dataset file (connection ID)
With DailyShout3.Worksheets(1).Rows(1)
    Set d = .Find("Days Past Due", LookIn:=xlValues)
        DPDEndColumnNumber = d.Column
    'Convert To Column Letter
    DPDEndColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, DPDEndColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
    DPDEndNumberCol = d.Column + 1
End If
End With

With DailyShout3.Worksheets(1).Rows(1)
    Set e = .Find("Account Number", LookIn:=xlValues)
        AccDSColumnNumber = e.Column
    'Convert To Column Letter
    AccDSColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, AccDSColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    If Not e Is Nothing Then
    AccDSNumberCol = e.Column + 1
End If
End With

'VLValue represents the range for the VLookup
VLValue = DPDEndColumnNumber - AccDSColumnNumber + 1

For i = 2 To LastRow

MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(sheet).Cells(i, DPDEndMRColumnNumber).Value2 = _
  Application.VLookup(MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(sheet).Range(AccColumnLetter & i), DailyShout3. _
    Worksheets(1).Range(AccDSColumnLetter & ":" & DPDEndColumnLetter), VLValue, 0)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Use variant arrays and iterate those.

Comment: I can help you if you want to convert it into PL/SQL.

Comment: Chances are that your Microsoft subscription includes Access. You can open Access, select **External Data**, **New Data Source** and then import your Excel. After this, you can create any number and type of query you need, and even export results back to Excel.

Comment: @stifin no need to do that you can run an SQL query on Excel sheets too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table • Probably anything is faster than (single-threading) VBA looping on huge data.

Comment: Scott - how would you use variant arrays in this instance? I'm not too familiar with arrays.

Comment: @peh thanks for sharing that - I read through it and am familiar with those options. If the asker must keep the operation inside Excel then, yes, he could connect from Excel to Excel. I *hope* he is already using Tables! Others: if he does **Get Data** > **From File** > **From Workbook** then he will use M query, which has a higher learning curve than Access queries/SQL. If he does **From Other Sources** > **From Microsoft Query** this brings up the old OLE-DB dialog box I remember from 20 years ago in VB6. Access faster and easier IMO. But these are all options for him to consider, for sure.

Comment: I do agree that anything is going to be faster than programming VBA to loop through a huge number of rows. If @DannyO'Sullivan is not familiar with arrays, then there is the learning curve and coding time to consider, too (no disrespect intended). Excel is not a DBMS. Access is optimized to process and query large datasets.

Comment: In cases where you are performing numerous `Vlookup` operations across the same range, I generally advocate for the use of a dictionary. Load the lookup range into the dictionary, then iterate over your data range, grabbing values from the dictionary instead of `Vlookup`. I ran a quick test. It took about 10 seconds to load 500k values into the dictionary, then another 20ish seconds to perform 500k lookups against that range.