# Need help creating an Excel macro to filter and total data (No experience in Excel!)

Tags: excel

I have the output of a cell counting software that looks something like this:

```
Column A: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3

Column B: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4

Column C: 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
```

In markdown format

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |

I want the macro to go through and hide all the rows except the first and last for each number in column A, with a new row added after the last 1, last 2, etc. In the new row, I want the last number from Column B to be copied and also the total sum of Column C for the all the rows with the same Column A number. So for example, the row after 1 would look like

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 5 | 3 |

(A is blank). I'd also like the totaling done for Column C to extend through Column Q.

If anyone could help me with this, I would be so grateful as currently I've just been doing this by hand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If we refactor your example to look more like an excel spreadsheet or database table it might be easier to understand your question:

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q

1 1 0

1 2 1

1 3 1

1 4 1

1 5 0

2 1 1

2 2 0

2 3 1

3 1 0

3 2 0

3 3 1

3 4 1

If this was a database table we could compose a SQL statement like

SELECT Max(A), Max(B), Sum(C), Sum(D), ..., Sum(Q) From table group by A

or maybe follow these suggestions:
[How to run a SQL query on an Excel table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table)

Excel is not the best place to save and analyze this example. You might find it easier to dump this data into an MS Access table. Then use a query to get the final results.

If you must use excel and need a macro to hide rows this is what I found:

```
Sub vba_hide_row_columns()
   'hide the row 1 to 4
   Range("1:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubCells()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim DblRow As Double
    Dim StrValueA As String
    Dim DblSumC As Double
    Dim DblLastB As Double
    Dim RngEnd As Range
    
    DblRow = 1
    
    Set RngEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
    
    Do
        
        If StrValueA = Cells(DblRow, 1).Value2 Or StrValueA = "" Then
            
CP_New_Section:
            
            If StrValueA <> "" And Cells(DblRow, 1).Value2 = Cells(DblRow + 1, 1).Value2 Then
                Cells(DblRow, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
            
            StrValueA = Cells(DblRow, 1).Value2
            DblLastB = Cells(DblRow, 2)
            DblSumC = DblSumC + Cells(DblRow, 3)
            
        Else
            
            StrValueA = ""
            Rows(DblRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Cells(DblRow, 2) = DblLastB
            Cells(DblRow, 3) = DblSumC
            DblRow = DblRow + 1
            DblSumC = 0
            GoTo CP_New_Section
            Stop
            
        End If
        
        DblRow = DblRow + 1
        
    Loop Until Cells(DblRow, 1).Address = RngEnd.Address
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what you mean by «I'd also like the totaling done for Column C to extend through Column Q», but if you want to report the result in all the cells from column C to column Q for the given row, just change the line `Cells(DblRow, 3) = DblSumC` into `Range(Cells(DblRow, 3), Cells(DblRow, 17)) = DblSumC`.